# Missing libqt3-mt in 13.04

Tags: 13.04, package-management, synaptic, qt, qt3

I have an application that requires the `libqt3-mt` package, in particular it's asking for `libqt-mt.so.3`. It worked OK under Ubuntu 12.04, but I've recently upgraded to 13.04 and the package is missing here (in Synaptic Package Manager). Could you please tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope they put again in repos, meanwhile u can download from:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/libqt3-mt/download

cheers

Award

Answer (score 2):

This can still be downloaded from the following links

For i386:  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/i386/libqt3-mt/3:3.3.8-b-8ubuntu3

For x86_64: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/amd64/libqt3-mt/3:3.3.8-b-8ubuntu3

In my case (on ubuntu 14.04 LTS), I first needed to install liblcms1 and libmng1:

**sudo apt-get install liblcms1**

download libmng package similar to with libqt3-mt: 
(i don't have enough rep to post more links, sorry )

**sudo dpkg --install /download_dir/libmng1_blah_blah.deb**

**sudo dpkg --install /download_dir/libqt3-mt_blah_blah.deb**