# Installing Firstclass missing dependency

Tags: software-installation

So I'm working for a school and they want me to install a communication program called firstclass.  It has a .deb called fcc-10.014-linux.i686.deb.  I tried clicking on it and it opened the software center.  It said dependency not satisfiable libqt3-mt|libqt3c102-mt.

The instructions say:

```
Command Line Installation Instructions

Debian Intel (Also for use on Ubuntu, Knoppix, and other Debian x86 derivatives):
        # su
        Password: ******
        # dpkg -i fcc-10.014-Linux.i686.deb
```

When I type these nothing happens.  Do I need to direct it to a directory where it is stored?  I tried throwing the file in home and navigating the terminal there to put in the commands.  Firstclass is a free download from here http://www.firstclass.com/Resources/ClientDownloads

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to set this up on?  The error you are getting suggests that there's missing dependencies or that they didn't write it right in the debian control file...

Comment: Aren't you typing the leading `#`, are you? You shouldn't!

Answer (score 0):

Here one person had missed libqt3-mt package in 13.04:
[Missing libqt3-mt in 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293854/missing-libqt3-mt-in-13-04)

Try to download that package from the link put there and install it.
Later, try again to install firstclass and to tell us.

Comment: I tried adding 'deb http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/ lucid main' to the source list via the Software Sources gui in ubuntu.  Now all my package managers are crashing as well as the Software Sources dialog. Synaptic says E: Malformed line 60 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
Go to the repository dialog to correct the problem.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
W: Ignoring file 'lightzone.listsudo' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

Comment: Which version of ubuntu do you have? And 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: You needn't add the source, just click on mirror you like on that page (http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/libqt3-mt/download).
If that source generates you problems, then remove it.

Comment: I'm using 64Bit.  Unfortunately the damage is done.  Now I need to learn how to fix my package management system.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Open a terminal and type: `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`
Look for _deb ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu lucid main_ and delete all that line. Probably it will be at line 60.
You can delete the additional lines with ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu but it should be preceded by a # so it doesn't matter.
Check synaptic now and tell.

Comment: In order to download libqt3-mt, 12.04 is the last version that has downloadable file in ubuntu package archive. You can download it for 64 bits here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/libqt3-mt/download  
I don't know if it would work in later versions of Ubuntu. You can just try.